# how to add columns with string variables in awk

Tags: awk

In linux, using a for loop, I want to generate each new txt file from a group of input txt files, by selecting two columns (column 1 and 4), and then adding new column 3, 4, and 5 with defined string variables. One of the input file names is:

```
E2_NCAPG_r1_UCSC_DNA_exon_fraction_counts.txt
```

For this input file, the output file I want is:

```
AluJb   165824  E2  DNA exon

AluSp   43328   E2  DNA exon

AluSc5  5753    E2  DNA exon
```

I tried:

```sh
for file in `ls E2*.txt`; do 
  treat=`echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f1` && 
  TE=`echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f5` && 
  region=`echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f6` && 
  awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1,$4,$3==treat,$4==TE,$5==region}' $file > ./E2_counts/${file}_tmp.txt
done
```

But it did not work.

Thanks for help!

Comment: First, ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason that is pitfall #1) Next, your example filename `E2_NCAPG_r1_UCSC_DNA_exon_fraction_counts.txt` does not provide the necessary information for you output. Last, make a temporary file containing all of the `E2*` filenames you want to manipulate and use the temporary file as input to a single call to `awk`. There is no need to `echo` piped to `cut` 3 times ever iteration before passing `"E2"`, `"DNA"` and `"exon"` as variables.

Comment: I will read your link, thank you David for help and great guide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
FNR==1 {                                # executed once for each filename
    split(FILENAME, a, "_")             # split the filename into array "a" on "_"
}
{
    print $1, $4, a[1], a[5], a[6]      # print columns of the file and the filename
}' E2*.txt > E2_counts
```

Comment: Thank you so much, tshiono. I edited your end by >> E2_counts.txt  It works great!

Comment: tshiono your approach is so amazing that it avoids looping. By using >> E2_counts.txt it actually also completes my desire to concatenate all tmp files in the end. Thank you!

Comment: Very good solution. @XiaoyongFu, `awk` is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. It can handle, on its own, everything a shell-script can and do it orders of magnitude faster. A great reference for learning `awk` is [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) There are other good tutorials available on the net as well.

Comment: Thank you, David! Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -1
E2_NCAPG_r1_UCSC_DNA_exon_fraction_counts.txt
E2_counts

$ more E2_NCAPG_r1_UCSC_DNA_exon_fraction_counts.txt
AluJb 0 0 165824
AluSp 0 0 43328
AluSc5 0 0 5753

$ for file in $(ls E2*.txt); do awk -v treat=$(echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f1) -v TE=$(echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f5) -v region=$(echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f6) 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1,$4,treat,TE,region}' $file > ./E2_counts/${file}_tmp.txt; done

$ more E2_counts/E2_NCAPG_r1_UCSC_DNA_exon_fraction_counts.txt_tmp.txt
AluJb   165824  E2      DNA     exon
AluSp   43328   E2      DNA     exon
AluSc5  5753    E2      DNA     exon
```

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Thank you prosperRob! I tested your code and it also works. Yet as commented by David, I will read the reason why it not suggested to use for loop here. Thank you all for answering my question and chances for learning more!